# SharePoint content restored but websites missing

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

I have restored a content database to SharePoint 2010 (which we completely broke after upgrading TFS to 2013).

When I open the content site, all the sub-sites are listed, but clicking one of these "sub-sites" goes to page not found. (The sub sites were created from TFS 2012 when new team projects were created).

How do I get the team project sites to work again?

Answer (score 1):

You likley do not have a managed path configured for your SharePoint sites. If you look at the URL of the sites that you can't see you should be able to figure out the managed paths to add.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845(v=office.15).aspx

You are kinda defining mount points for site collections here. Without that mount point SharePoint will not render your sites.

Comment: The path /sites was already there. I have added /sites/DefaultCollection but what else do I need to add if my Team Project was called "ProjectX"?

Comment: Can you give us the paths to some of the Project sites? is it "/sites/defaultcollection/myproject?

Comment: Yeah I thought it was that, but without being able to see them I cannot be 100% certain! Nothing was changed, so if that is the "out of the box" TFS team project path then that is what it should be.

Comment: I would need to get my hands on the system to debug further, there are a lot of things it could be...